# Clock-pro cache - java implementation

Tags: java, caching, clock

*Hello, everyone.*

I strongly need to implement in short period of time, Clock-Pro caching algorithm in Java.
But I only have an official article: [Clock-Pro: an effective improvement of thr Clock Replacement](http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~fchen/paper/papers/usenix05.pdf)

It's unreally hard for me to understand algorithm, described there. Maybe It was written just in general. Also I know it's implemented in linux kernel, I think it' much more hard than official article:(

I suppose it must be smth like:

```java
public class ClockProCache<K,V>
```

Where we can put an object , and it will correct replace other one with true Clock-Pro logic.

If anyone maybe had some experience or attempts in this topic, please help with java implementation.

Comment: Why two [same](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10006770/617996) questions?

Comment: Reposting is the worst choice to get attention. If you just edited the one question you posted, it would have been just the same. Try to provide more proof of research and effort on your part.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my Python 3 implementation which you can use as a sample code. The paper you're referring to, isn't exactly easy to understand. I hd to read it about 10 times and spent a good while thinking, what they're really after. I'll hope this helps.

https://bitbucket.org/SamiLehtinen/pyclockpro

P.S. It's good idea to study LIRS too, CLOCK-Pro is basically a LIRS approximation. Just like basic CLOCK is LRU approximation.